# Calling a function in App from a different Screen component in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm developing an app for tuning pianos in react-native.
I have an App.js and some screens implemented with react-navigation. The question is, how I can call a function in App.js from another Screen component in react-native?
I'm missing something of react-native, I searched on the web but I can't find something really useful.

The App.js code:

```js
export default class App extends Component {

...

testFunction = () => {
  ...
}


render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Tab.Navigator activeColor="#000" barStyle={{           backgroundColor: "white" }}>
            <Tab.Screen
              name="Tuner"
              component={TunerScreen}
              options={{
                tabBarLabel: "Home",
                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color="black" size={26} />
                ),
              }}
            />

            <Tab.Screen
              name="Beats"
              component={BeatsScreen}
              options={{
                tabBarLabel: "Beats",
                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons
                    name="blur-radial"
                    color="black"
                    size={26}
                  />
                ),
              }}
            />

            <Tab.Screen
              name="Inharmonicity"
              component={InharmonicityScreen}
              options={{
                tabBarLabel: "Parameters",
                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="cog" color="black" size={26} />
                ),
              }}
            />
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </Provider>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
  
}
```

And the Screen component code:

```js
class TunerScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={style.body}>
        ...
        <Button
          style={style.btn}
          onPress={() => testFunction()} //Here i want to call the function
          title="Start"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Start"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to pass the props like this

```
<Tab.Screen
              name="Inharmonicity"
              component={(props) => <InharmonicityScreen testFunction={this.testFunction} {...props} />}
              options={{
                tabBarLabel: "Parameters",
                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="cog" color="black" size={26} />
                ),
              }}
            />
```

Remember to use `this.testFunction = this.testFunction.bind(this)`

Then in desire Screen you can use `props.testFunction()` after declaring `super(props)` in constructor.